# Active Class on div from the url

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a twitter Bootstrap Carousel and I am trying to link to its seperate slide from external pages. I need to do it using a url.

etc.

```
http://www.example.com/carousel.html#item3:active
```

to set the third slide as active

Is there a way I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly possible. You can get the part after the `#` in the current URL via `document.location.hash`, and you can link to a specific slide with `$('.some-carousel').carousel(slideNr)`. Put together, your code might look like the following:

```
$(function () {
  var slide = document.location.hash.match(/^slide-(\d+)$/);
  if (slide) {
    $('.some-carousel').carousel(parseInt(slide[1], 10));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to explain the cotnents of (/^slide-(\d+)$/) and (slide[1], 10) ??? Also should i put this script on the header or the end of the document?

Comment: Sure! `/^slide-(\d+)$/` is a Regular Expression which matches strings like `slide-10` or `slide-6`. So, we check whether the URL is of the form `http://example.com/some/path#slide-8`. The `parseInt(slide[1], 10)` converts the string `"8"` to the number `8`.

Comment: Could you please check my code. I am doing something wrong and I cannot find it. [link](http://www.ideoptimo.gr/carousel/index.html)

Comment: I don't see anything which looks like the code I posted in the answer.